# Multiple Apps Using the Same Controller - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have a header that is used on every page on my website. This header containers menu items, searches, etc. I have a controller called 'HeaderController' that is used in the menu. I also have another controller that is used for the main content of the page. I have the following code that allows me to use two controllers:

```
 angular.module('customersApp')
   .controller('HeaderController', HeaderController)
```

I run into a problem when I am trying to use this same file on pages outside of the 'customersApp.' For example I have a 'deliveryApp' and when I try to run the top header on a page within the 'deliveryApp' I get an error saying that the 'customersApp' is not available, which I would expect.

I do not want to make a new header and file for each section of my website due to having to make changes to 5 different pages instead of 1. I am looking for a way to include all of my apps in the above code. Thanks.

Comment: Have you injected `customersApp` in your `deliveryApp` as a dependency?

Comment: No that isn't something I am familiar with.

Comment: You have created two modules, right? Like such `angular.module('deliveryApp', []);` For `deliveryApp` to have access to the header you need to inject `customersApp` into it like this: `angular.module('deliveryApp', ['customersApp']);`

Comment: Okay. I actually have 5 different modules. Would the same concept apply?

Comment: Yes, it would. Are you using a kickstarter such as Yeoman or ng-boilerplate?

Comment: No I am not using either of those kickstarter programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a common module for your header controller:

```
angular.module("common", [])
  .controller("HeaderController", HeaderController);
```

Then, add this module as a depdendency into other apps.

```
angular.module("deliveryApp", ["common"]);
```

and

```
angular.module("customersApp", ["common"]);
```

Make sure that the actual js file for common is also included in `index.html` of each of the apps.